# The right way to use a custom library in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have a custom library to be included in Qt. Currently, it is included by adding the followings in .pro file.

```
INCLUDEPATH += ...
DEPENDPATH += ...
LIB += ...
```

Since the library is used in most of my projects. I am wondering that if there is some way to make my custom library to be INTEGRATED with the QtSDK? Maybe it can be included by syntax like the build-in components

```
QT += my_custom_library
```

and everything (header file include path, lib file include, etc...) will be done.

Is the integration possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for to create a mkspec file which then used with CONFIG option. So create a file to $QT_HOME/mkspec/features/mycoollib.prf that contains your instructions. There should be plenty of examples in that directory. The name of the file declares it's usage, so the file mycoollib.prf would be used like:

```
CONFIG += mycoollib
```