# Linking to Shared Library in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I've just created tinyxml as a shared library, and would like to figure out how to link it. How is this accomplished?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689890/the-right-way-to-use-a-custom-library-in-qt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add includepath and libs in your pro file.

Something like the following. Just change your paths.

```
LIBS += -ltinyxml

LIBS += -L/libs/tinyxml/lib

INCLUDEPATH += /libs/tinyxml/include/
```

Comment: Are you referring to the makefile itself?

Comment: I am reffering to the .pro file. The one that qmake parses in order to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you your library resides in the project directory, the following line may come in handy:

```
LIBS += -L$${PWD}
```