# Calling function from dll with QT

Tags: c++, qt, dll, segmentation-fault

I created by the first time a dll to use with C++ (and then C#, I have plans to share this dll between a C++ and C# applications) using QT creator but when I try to use it I get SEGFAULT error.

Here's my files:

**mydll.h**

```
#ifndef MYDLL_H
#define MYDLL_H

#include "mydll_global.h"

class MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT MyDll
{

public:
    MyDll();
    int getAnswer();
};


MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT int getNumber();

#endif // MYDLL_H
```

**mydll_global.h**

```
#ifndef MYDLL_GLOBAL_H
#define MYDLL_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(MYDLL_LIBRARY)
#  define MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MYDLL_GLOBAL_H
```

mydll.cpp

```
#include "mydll.h"


MyDll::MyDll()
{
}

int MyDll::getAnswer()
{
    return 42;
}

int getNumber()
{
    return 10;
}
```

So I build it and created `mydll.dll`: then I went to other C++ project wheere I want to use this dll and put in the `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += "C:\path\to\mydll.h"
```

and in the main.cpp

```
#include "mydll.h"
```

and when I use function from dll like this:

```
 qDebug() << getNumber();
```

I get a `SEGFAULT` error.

I thought that the header to provide the compiler type information and the dll to compiler to provide the function body was all I needed but as I'm getting a `SEGFAULT` I'm acessing `NULL` or someone else memory or so (I can't see the value on debug).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, to link the DLL you need the link .lib file for that DLL. That file has all the binary manifest for linking.

Second, project file LIBS clause specify the list of .lib files to link with. Some of them may represent dynamic libraries (.dll).

See the example: [Linking to Shared Library in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182229/linking-to-shared-library-in-qt)

Even better article covering both creation of DLL with Qt and using DLL in your Qt project: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Almost every example I looked at had a `class` as their example, but I wanted to export functions like `getNumber()`. It's in the qt5 docs as you probably know by now.

This line needs to be in your header file:

```
extern "C" MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT int getNumber();
```

and it is either the `mydll_global.h` or `mydll.h` depending on what you are using.

`mydll_global.h` would be what qtcreator creates and puts export definitions in if you create a new `Shared Library` project.

I was thrown off guard by the `extern "C"` part as I wasn't using C and wasn't as familiar with how compilers export symbols.

Trying to add a `public` `static` function to a `class` definition using `static MYDLLSHARED_EXPORT int getNumber();` or simply using a namespace (function defined with or without static) will give a `not found for architecture x86_64` error using clang on osx.