# Linux and macOS are fine, but Windows build throws linker error LNK2019

Tags: c++, qt, linker, linker-errors

I'm calling a class method in a shared library from within another shared library. Application builds fine on Linux and macOS but on Windows I receive:

> exportlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::vector > __cdecl Algorithmslib::k_means(class std::vector > const &,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)" (__imp_?k_means@Algorithmslib@@QEAA?AV?$vector@VPoint@@V?$allocator@VPoint@@@std@@@std@@AEBV23@_K1@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl Exportlib::setSuppPoints(void)" (?setSuppPoints@Exportlib@@AEAAXXZ)
>   debug\exportlib.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I ran out of ideas what might cause the error (only on Windows!)

---

#### Shared library with exported class:

```cpp
// Project file for exported shared library
// algorithmslib.pro

DEFINES += ALGORITHMSLIB_LIBRARY
```

Export or import according to defines:

```cpp
// algorithmslib_global.h

#if defined(ALGORITHMSLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define ALGORITHMSLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define ALGORITHMSLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

Class declaration:

```cpp
// algorithmslib.h

#include "algorithmslib_global.h"

class ALGORITHMSLIBSHARED_EXPORT Algorithmslib : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Algorithmslib();
    std::vector<Point> k_means(const std::vector<Point>& data,
                               size_t k,
                               size_t number_of_iterations);
};
```

---

#### Calling `k_means` method of exported class from within another shared library:

```cpp
// This is a second shared library which calls the exported class of the 1st shared library
// exportlib.cpp

#include "algorithmslib.h"

void Exportlib::setSuppPoints()
{
    Algorithmslib algorithmEngine;
    std::vector<Point> means = algorithmEngine.k_means(data, k, number_of_iterations);
}
```

---

I'm compiling with Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug kit:

[image: Compilers]

---

I renamed the shared library to something very unique, and yet the same linker error is thrown. Therefore, [this issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73959) is NOT my case

Comment: Is `k_means` function defined?

Comment: how do you build your application ? Build command line would be interesting.
If it build on linux/mac it should as well on windows. Are you using visual studio ?

Comment: @vahancho Yes, `k_means` is implemented in source code, that's why build is fine on Linux and macOS :)

Comment: @AF_cpp I'm using Qt Creator. I have deleted the build directory and repeated the build process multiple times, but no luck :(

Comment: @user3405291, some linkers do not complain when you call a function that has only declaration and no definition. In such cases you detect the problem only at run-time.

Comment: This might be a problem with name mangling. Did you check if both shared libraries are compiled using the same compiler?

Comment: Do other calls inside the same library work ? Maybe you should check the qtCreator documentation for how to specify dll dependencies.

Comment: @Annyo Right. It can be something [like this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73959)

Comment: @user3405291 Yes, it might be that, but that's not what I meant. I was talking about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work). Basically, name mangling is a step required for linking in C++, but different compilers do that differently, thus you can't link with a compiler against a library compiled by another compiler.

Comment: @Annyo Thanks :) I double-checked, Qt Creator is using the same build tools for all shared libraries.

Comment: Maybe I should have started there: did you [update your .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182229/linking-to-shared-library-in-qt) correctly to link against the shared library ? (I think you did, since it is compiling on Linux and MacOS, make sure the paths are correct too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First shared lib

I have a `struct` inside 1st shared library:

```
// algorithmslib.h

struct Point {
    float x{0}, y{0}, z{0};
};
```

#### Second shared lib

I was using the above `struct` inside my 2nd shared library like this:

header:

```
// exportlib.h

class Point; // Note that I was using "class" here 
             // but the declaration inside algorithmslib.h is "struct"

size_t computeNumberOfClusters(const std::vector<Point> &data);
```

source:

```
//exportlib.cpp

#include "algorithmslib.h"

std::vector<Point> data(number_of_points); // Point structure is declared in algorithmslib.h

size_t k = computeNumberOfClusters(data);
size_t number_of_iterations = 300;
Algorithmslib algorithmEngine;

std::vector<Point> means = algorithmEngine.k_means(data, k, number_of_iterations);
```

#### Fix

I changed the header for 2nd shared library from `class Point;` to `struct Point;` and linker error on Windows got resolved:

```
// exportlib.h

struct Point; // declared in algorithmslib.h as "struct" NOT "class"
```

Comment: I wonder why Linux (gcc-g++) and macOS (clang++) don't care about `class` and `struct` mis-match!